# SharePoint Designer Internal Status should be updated in a status column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, javascript, designer-workflow

SharePoint Designer Workflow Internal Status Should be updated in column is this possible using workflow or is there any other way if so please explain how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by internal status?

Comment: If you mean workflow internal status being "Starting", "Started", "Failed to start" etc then i don't think its possible to update in workflow designer. By the way why would you need to update that? It is workflow status and should be updated only by SharePoint workflow foundation itself.